# how to set up nginx as reverse proxy (bastion); i have "400Bad Request: too many Host headers"

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I try to set up nginx to authenticate incoming https request and pass them on to a server on a different host in the same intranet (LAN). from different sources i arrived at the following conf file:

```
    proxy_redirect              off;
    proxy_set_header            Host            $http_host;
    proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header            X-Forwared-For  proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

upstream syncthing_gui 
  {
      server 10.0.0.129:8329; 
  }

server {
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  geras.duckdns.org;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/letsencrypt/live/geras.duckdns.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/letsencrypt/live/geras.duckdns.org/privkey.pem;

    auth_basic "Username and Password required (syncthing)";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

  location /sync {

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info; 
    access_log /var/log/access.log;
    proxy_pass http://syncthing_gui;
}
```

}

but i get the error `400 Bad Request: too many Host headers`. what do i have to change?

Comment: Place your `proxy_redirect` and `proxy_set_header` directives in the `location /sync` block and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 9):

This message is not from nginx, but from [Golang](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/c80e0d374ba3caf8ee32c6fe4a5474fa33928086/src/net/http/server.go#L786) (Syncthing is written in Go). At first blush, I interpreted this error to mean that there were too many, or too large headers being sent to nginx. But what it *really* means is there are too many `Host: abc.example.com` headers.

In your configuration, you have

`proxy_set_header            Host            $http_host;`

I would bet that in some other configuration file, you have a duplicate or similar line, which causes nginx to send the server two HTTP `Host:` headers. Most software doesn't care about this, but Go's standard HTTP server checks for this and rejects requests with a **400**.